# get mysql records just from today with offset

Tags: mysql, datetime, timezone

I'm trying to get all the records just for today but having trouble. Another thing I'm unsure of how to factor in is that my server time is two hours ahead of my local time so I'll need to figure out the offset. I'm off setting the time when I'm inserting the data just not sure how to do it on retrieval of if I'll need to.

```
mysql_query("SELECT `* FROM table WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) <= `date` AND `alert_status` ='0'") or die(mysql_error());
```

I think part of the problem is the `<=` I tried just using `=` and `==` but neither worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly is the problem you're running into?  What do you mean when you say that it doesn't work?

I see a syntax error (the backtick right before the asterisk), but I'm not sure what your issue is.  That `DATE_SUB` call looks reasonable to me.

**Edit**: try something like this:

```
WHERE `date` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND CURDATE()
```

...which is just a fancy way of doing this:

```
WHERE `date` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND `date` <= CURDATE()
```

Comment: I'm trying to only get dates from today. Currently it's getting dates today and later. I'm also worried about the timezone offset. (The asterisk was just a type from pulling into stack)

Comment: I tried to update my answer in response to what you've said.  You could be a bit more specific about what isn't working - are you having issues because CURDATE() uses the server's time?

Are the dates that you insert being adjusted to be correct in the server's timezone?  If not, then you'll have to do something jankety like DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOURS)) in place of the CURDATE() calls.